# Weird text/characters in input boxes--Help!

Tags: html, codeigniter

I just re-opened a website I'm developing, and my submit buttons are freaking out!

I really don't have any idea what happened, and rather than root around the 20+ components I've been working on, I thought I'd ask the experts first.

What can cause this?  Any ideas?

[What's going on!? http://img30.imageshack.us/img30/7616/screenshot20100119at221.png](http://img30.imageshack.us/img30/7616/screenshot20100119at221.png)

Comment: Wrong encoding send to/used by  browser?

Comment: If you're using Firefox, this would be a good time to insepect that element with Firebug. Alternatively, if you're using Chrome, you can do the same by right-clicking it, and selecting "inspect element."

Comment: @Jonathan, your comment led me to the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Bummer, I should have posted it as an answer :) Good work, Kevin!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using Firefox? Does that button call for Helvetica in its CSS? Do you have Helvetica installed on your system? If the answers to those questions are "yes," then I know your problem. Try reinstalling Helvetica and rebooting.

EDIT: Try looking at the headlines on Smashing Magazine. They use Helvetica. I had this problem before, and it looked like this:

---

[image]

Comment: You're the man.  It wasn't helvetica, it was Arial...but the solution worked.

Comment: +1 Hah, you're really the Man Kerrick! Does anybody have any background info on why this happens?